# How does Fileset work using Maven Ant Resolver/?

Tags: maven, ant, fileset

I have a query in old Ant file which I want to migrate into maven

<artifact:dependencies filesetId="objrelationshipmigration.fileset" useScope="runtime">

</artifact:dependencies>

Need help on how to use it using resolver?

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: I have to completely eliminate the use of this